# How can i run code with a compilor

Tags: vb.net

I am developing an IDE for AutoIt (A scripting language) in vb.net. (In VS2013). I am using scintillaNet for the ide. IDE is almost ready. But i don't know how to run the code in the ide with AutoIt.exe. Any help ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After 24 hours of asking this question, i have found the answer myself. 
There is command for running scripts in every interpreter. For AutoIt, it is "Path of Interpreter" & " " & Path of script".
So you have to use Shell function in vb.net like this;

```
Shell("Path of Interpreter" & " " & "Path of script")
```

This code will run the script.